# how to make animation transition between fragments in navigation by drawer in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I have a drawer in my app and I switch fragments by navigation. I would like to have animation transition  when I click on the button in the drawer. I know how to do it with regular button but I do not konw how to do it with navigation drawer Thank you.

this is my main Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.nav_food_text_analysis,
            R.id.nav_recipe_analysis
        ), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }


}
```

this is my navigation xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav_food_text_analysis">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_food_text_analysis"
        android:name="com.example.nutritionfacts.ui.foodTextAnalysis.FoodAnalysisFragment"
        android:label="Food analysis"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_food_text_analysis" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_food_text_analysis_to_nav_recipe_analysis"
            app:destination="@id/nav_recipe_analysis"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/enter_from_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/exit_to_right"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/enter_from_right"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/exit_to_right" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_recipe_analysis"
        android:name="com.example.nutritionfacts.ui.recipeAnalysis.RecipeAnalysisFragment"
        android:label="Recipe analysis"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_recipe_analysis" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_recipe_analysis_to_nav_food_text_analysis2"
            app:destination="@id/nav_food_text_analysis"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/enter_from_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/exit_to_right"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/enter_from_right"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/exit_to_right" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just working on this and have a solution that listens for the navigation drawer clicks and reacts in the same way you would with a button.

I am using a single activity with several fragments. Make sure to set up the navigtaion graph for your fragments, then call the correct `FragmentDirections` action by using the `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` in the Main Activity.

In my example, the `settingsFragment` will be loaded with an animation but the `aboutFragment` will not since it doesn't call a `Directions.action` function.

**MainActivity (inside onCreate function)**

```
        /** Handle clicks in Nav Drawer **/
        val navigationView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.navView)
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
            Timber.d("Nav Drawer Item Clicked: %s", menuItem.title)
            when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.settingsFragment -> {
                    navController.navigate(
                        RecipeListFragmentDirections
                        .actionRecipeListToSettingsFragment()
                    )
                }
                R.id.aboutFragment -> {
                    navController.navigate(R.id.aboutFragment)
                }
                R.id.refreshRecipes -> {
                    Timber.i("TODO: Implement repository refresh method call")
                }
            }

            true
        }
```

**navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/recipeList">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/recipeList"
        android:name="com.jumptuck.recipebrowser2.recipelist.RecipeListFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_recipe_list">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_recipeList_to_singleRecipeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/singleRecipeFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_recipeList_to_aboutFragment"
            app:destination="@id/aboutFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_recipeList_to_settingsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/settingsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left" />
    </fragment>
```

One of the reasons I've used this approach is because I want to start a service from the `refreshRecipes` menu item rather than causing a navigation and this intercepts the click. One of the drawbacks is that the navigation bar items themselves don't show an animation when clicked (however I think this can be fixed).